# Why do my items have some horizontal lines after the deletion operation?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have now hidden the split line of the list, but after performing the delete operation, there will be more split lines. What should I do?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "datacell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)as!
        AppsTableViewCell


    // 去掉列表的分隔线
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a footerview to tableview.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Comment: Thanks, there is a line in my tableview to eliminate the horizontal line of the list, but after deleting the list data, the horizontal line comes out again.

Comment: Are you sure updating the number of rows in section, updating data count ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you said.……

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have found the problem in my code, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The better approach to set properties related to tableView that remains the same in the viewController is in **viewDidLoad()** of the current viewController.

So put below these two lines of code in viewDidLoad() to avoid separator between the actual and empty rows.

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

Comment: This line of code has been added to viewDidLoad, but it is still the same. After deleting a row of data, it will display a horizontal line.

Comment: @张子恒  are you reloading the tableview after deleting ?

Comment: @张子恒 then please share some more code of your viewcontroller so one can guide you properly what’s going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have found the problem in my code, thank you again